# MongoDB allocate a lot of memory when concurrent update single document

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, parallel-processing, mongodb-.net-driver

Could anyone explain to me the situation when mongo allocates a lot of memory while concurrently updates single document.

What I'm talking about:

I have one document with structure like this:

```
{ id, data: [{id, status}] }
```

*Data* field has a lot of objects inside (in my testing case 5000 objects).

In test I just update each *data* object in single document.

When I do it synchronously there are no extra memory allocations. But when I update document in parallel, mongo allocates more than 2GB extra memory.

There are allocations in first case (synchronous):

```html
{
    "pageheap_free_bytes" : 23552000,
    "pageheap_unmapped_bytes" : 0,
    "max_total_thread_cache_bytes" : NumberLong(1073741824),
    "current_total_thread_cache_bytes" : 994032,
    "total_free_bytes" : 7793496,
    "central_cache_free_bytes" : 4958056,
    "transfer_cache_free_bytes" : 1841408,
    "thread_cache_free_bytes" : 994032,
    "aggressive_memory_decommit" : 0,
    "pageheap_committed_bytes" : 112832512,
    "pageheap_scavenge_count" : 0,
    "pageheap_commit_count" : 85,
    "pageheap_total_commit_bytes" : 112832512,
    "pageheap_decommit_count" : 0,
    "pageheap_total_decommit_bytes" : 0,
    "pageheap_reserve_count" : 85,
    "pageheap_total_reserve_bytes" : 112832512,
    "spinlock_total_delay_ns" : NumberLong(1169495344),
    "formattedString" : "------------------------------------------------\nMALLOC:       81487592 (   77.7 MiB) Bytes in use by application\nMALLOC: +     23552000 (   22.5 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist\nMALLOC: +      4958056 (    4.7 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist\nMALLOC: +      1841408 (    1.8 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist\nMALLOC: +       993456 (    0.9 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists\nMALLOC: +      2318592 (    2.2 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata\nMALLOC:   ------------\nMALLOC: =    115151104 (  109.8 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)\nMALLOC: +            0 (    0.0 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)\nMALLOC:   ------------\nMALLOC: =    115151104 (  109.8 MiB) Virtual address space used\nMALLOC:\nMALLOC:           2618              Spans in use\nMALLOC:             25              Thread heaps in use\nMALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size\n------------------------------------------------\nCall ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS (via madvise()).\nBytes released to the OS take up virtual address space but no physical memory.\n"
}
```

And the second one:

```html
{
    "pageheap_free_bytes" : 1020854272,
    "pageheap_unmapped_bytes" : 13770752,
    "max_total_thread_cache_bytes" : NumberLong(1073741824),
    "current_total_thread_cache_bytes" : 1996120,
    "total_free_bytes" : 24262888,
    "central_cache_free_bytes" : 19604560,
    "transfer_cache_free_bytes" : 2662208,
    "thread_cache_free_bytes" : 1996120,
    "aggressive_memory_decommit" : 0,
    "pageheap_committed_bytes" : NumberLong(2859118592),
    "pageheap_scavenge_count" : 51,
    "pageheap_commit_count" : 2781,
    "pageheap_total_commit_bytes" : NumberLong(2886373376),
    "pageheap_decommit_count" : 51,
    "pageheap_total_decommit_bytes" : 27254784,
    "pageheap_reserve_count" : 2690,
    "pageheap_total_reserve_bytes" : NumberLong(2872889344),
    "spinlock_total_delay_ns" : NumberLong(158962109950),
    "formattedString" : "------------------------------------------------\nMALLOC:     1814002008 ( 1730.0 MiB) Bytes in use by application\nMALLOC: +   1020854272 (  973.6 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist\nMALLOC: +     19604560 (   18.7 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist\nMALLOC: +      2662208 (    2.5 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist\nMALLOC: +      1995544 (    1.9 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists\nMALLOC: +     12574976 (   12.0 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata\nMALLOC:   ------------\nMALLOC: =   2871693568 ( 2738.7 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)\nMALLOC: +     13770752 (   13.1 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)\nMALLOC:   ------------\nMALLOC: =   2885464320 ( 2751.8 MiB) Virtual address space used\nMALLOC:\nMALLOC:          19410              Spans in use\nMALLOC:             28              Thread heaps in use\nMALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size\n------------------------------------------------\nCall ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS (via madvise()).\nBytes released to the OS take up virtual address space but no physical memory.\n"
}
```

As you can see **Bytes in use by application** and **Bytes in page heap freelist** increased from 77.7 / 22.5 MB to 1730 / 973.6 MB.

So if I run parallel code several times, these numbers increase linear.

Could anyone explain what's happening when mongo processes concurrent queries and how to prevent allocations?

In my tests I'm using mongoDb 4.0.4 ([here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) is a docker image) and [.net core client](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/).

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a sequential update you are doing it with a single thread. Which would only use a single connection.  Each connection tread can need up to 1MB. [as per docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#how-do-i-calculate-how-much-ram-i-need-for-my-application)

If you are doing parallel updates this would have multiple connection treads which each would use 1 MB, which would push the memory usage.